# Backbone.js SEO with Java based REST services

Tags: spring-mvc, backbone.js

Someone might argue that this is not a real question, I might agree...

I moved to backbone.js because it makes sense. Evertyhing, JSON, performance, separation of entities etc. Once I leaned it, developing became very easy and fast. Now that we started to implement SEO properly (we have a heavy content site) I found that this is not easy at all. I actually need to implement a unique server side controller for every call. Since some View/templates actually call several models while rendering(nested), I need to have much more complex SEO controllers on the server side.
This all means that I now have to develop unique controllers just for SEO. Way more development time than ever expected.

I'm very much aware of pushstate and how it should work. Still, I still need to implement the duplicate route on the server side controller. Or maybe I'm missing something.

Did anyone find a way to automate this using Java/REST frameworks ?
I have found this very cool Phantom.js integration and Node: [Backbone SEO and PhantomJS](http://backbonetutorials.com/seo-for-single-page-apps/)